# How to anticipate and avoid "code too large"?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr3

I am writing SQL grammar using Antlr 3.5 (which I cannot share due to company policy).

I am providing only for the statements which I need to parse but the grammar is huge and complex.

I ran into "code too large" issue where the generated java file was exceeding 65535 bytes- sometimes in static initializer, other times in some method.

As suggested at various places, I split the grammar into multiple grammars and used them via import keyword.

This approach is working fine for now but I have to keep adding to this grammar 
and I believe at some point it will again run into this code too large problem.
Also, I do not know exactly how much gain I have by splitting the grammar.

My questions are:

1. How do we know we are nearing code too large problem again?
2. Is there a way by which we can measure exactly how much improvement/gain
   we are getting by splitting the grammars.
3. The generated files are still huge - SqlParserParser.java is 1.77MB and 
   SqlParser_SqlSubParser.java is 1.36MB. 
   Is the file size an indication of this problem?
4. Is there anything else that can also be done besides grammar splitting.

Few points:

1. I cannot switch to Antlr4 as of now.
2. Please try not to down vote my question for the lack of example as I cannot post the real grammar and a small example would not recreate my problem.

Comment: With ANTLR3, I'm pretty sure you'll keep running into these errors with large (SQL) grammars. There's also little community support for v3, and this version is not being actively maintained. Porting your v3 grammar to v4 is by far the best thing you can do, IMO.

Comment: What does ANTLR4 do to avoid having the same problem?  THis has to do with Giant things and Java's limited code size rules.

Comment: @IraBaxter I don't know the specifics, but I know that many SQL grammars face this problem in v3 (and COBOL and Fortran too, I believe). This was something that v4 handles smarter, keeping these numbers in check

Comment: Have you tried to lower the number of rules (by combining them)? ANTLR generates recursive decent parsers and hence the number of functions in the generated parser directly correlates to the number of rules in the grammar. This will make the grammar uglier, but might bring you under the critical limit of the Java code size (which is reportedly also a problem with ANTLR4).

Comment: @MikeLischke I don't think that the number of rules is the problem because from what I know a java class can have at most 65535 methods and the number of methods is way less in my case..
As far as combining the rules, won't it generate more code for the combined method? I am not sure if this will actually help. Or if I am not understanding your point correctly, may be you can elaborate..

Comment: Well, that was just a wild guess. A while ago this Java error came up because the static table for the ATN data was too large, but meanwhile that has been split. I'm not a Java expert and hence don't know all possible reasons when a "code too large" error is produced.

Comment: I think java class files can't contain more than 65Kb of code.  A big grammar, used to generate a recursive descent parser, could run you out of code space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember, the problem isn't the class size itself, but rather method size. For us, the problem was the static initializer (to compiler, it's a method too!) - it initializes all the follow sets and DFAs.

We ended up splitting our SQL grammars into multiple grammar files (got even to 6 files for some SQL dialects), and also directly modifying parts of ANTLR (`Java.stg` template) to split the large methods and static initializers into smaller ones.

Comment: Your grammar was Antlr3 or Antlr4?

Comment: ANTLR 3. <added garbage text for comment length>

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. You have suggested 2 approaches- splitting the grammar and also modifying parts of Antlr (Java.stg template). Were they both required to handle this code too large problem? I am already on the verge of splitting my grammar file into 3 sub files now - Will modifying java.stg template help in this case or is splitting essential?

Comment: We ended up using both approaches together. Using just splitting may be viable although you might end up with large number of grammars, just editing ANTLR will most likely not be enough.

Comment: Do you have any idea if moving to Antlr4 will completely resolve the code too large problem or may be less splitting is required then? Also, can you share any pointers regarding modifying java.stg template..

Comment: Sorry, no idea about ANTLR4. It also wasn't me modifying the template, so I don't really have any good pointers.

Comment: The above post doesn't exactly answer my question of how to anticipate 'code too large' but it has quite a few helpful suggestions/comments. Hence, I am accepting this answer. Thanks.